Convert FormData to a list of objects
I have a form where a set of fields is repeated a couple of times. This form is then sent as FormData to the back-end.
My current solution is to name the fields in the form like this:
<input name="firstname" />
<input name="lastname" />
<input name="firstname" />
<input name="lastname" />

Then on the back-end, I can convert FormData to an array of objects like this:
const firstnames = formData.getAll('firstnames')
const lastnames = formData.getAll('lastnames')
const persons = []

for (let i = 0; i < firstnames.length; i++) {
    persons.push({
       firstname: firstnames[i],
       lastname: lastnames[i]
     })
}

Since this seems to be a pretty standard scenario, I am just guessing that I am not on the right track to convert form data to a list of objects like this. How can this be done?

It is not that straight forward. When you do a HTML request you need to decide in what format the data delivered to the back-end. In this case either as application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default for at form) or application/json (deliberately formatting a string with all the data). There is no option for delivering a FormData object. But the form data object could be useful in both cases. So, the question is, what you expect to get on the back-end?

Now that you have more "persons" it would be a good idea to send the data as application/json. You can group the input elements using <fieldset>. A fieldset has a property called elements -- a list of all the input elements in that fieldset. So, you can loop all the fieldsets on their name (person), create an object, and add that to an array. Then you can stringify the array and send it to the back-end as application/json.


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  
  // loop all fieldsets
  let data = [...form.person].map((person, i) => {
    return {
      'firstname': person.elements.firstname.value,
      'lastname': person.elements.lastname.value
      };
  });
  
  // send the form data object
  fetch(form.action, {
    method: form.method,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
});
<form name="form01" method="post" action="https://reqres.in/api/users">
  <fieldset name="person">
    <input name="firstname">
    <input name="lastname">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="person">
    <input name="firstname">
    <input name="lastname">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="person">
    <input name="firstname">
    <input name="lastname">
  </fieldset>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>




Thanks for your reply @chrwahl. Well, since I am using next.js with server actions as framework it really is as i described: after submitting the form my backend (server action) receives an FormData object which holds per specification only key -> value pairs. By altering the names of my formfields I can only decide how the keys look like. So, as decribed my challenge is to convert this FormData-Object which hold only key-value-pairs to a multi dimensional object with a list of objects.
